# How to play Embed youtube url on HTML canvas Element using javascript

Tags: javascript, video, canvas, youtube, html5-canvas

I am struggling how to play the **embed youtube url** on the **html canvas** element using JavaScript.

**Sample code which I tried**

```
videoAsset = document.createElement("video");
youtube = document.createElement("source");
youtube.src = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI";
youtube.type = "video/youtube";
videoAsset.appendChild(youtube);
```

or

```
<canvas id=c></canvas>
<video id=v controls loop>
    <source src=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI type=video/youtube>
    <source src=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI type=video/youtube>          
</video>
```

The above code doesn't works for me .

Comment: since they don't give you direct  access to the framed document, you're stuck. Except if you are writing a browser's extension, which may give you access to more powerful APIs allowing you to access the framed document and the graal video element.

Comment: youtube api uses iframe, its not canvas >:(
im also wondering same question, one idea im thinking is taking pixels from iframes and put it in canvas, not sure if this will work

Answer (score 0):

Since You are using youtube videos. why don't you use Youtube Api.[You tube api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)   .The api is clear and works well.The urls specified in the question will lead to iframe not videos mostly.Ad the Api alos provides lot of customization options.

Comment: Thanks for your response but i am looking in pure javascript/jquery . i dont want to use any youtube api or javascript iframe .

Comment: Is this possible without youtube api/iframe?

Comment: If you are using videos hosted in youtube.You dont' have choice but to use Api or embed script which exists just below the youtube video.